# Layout-start-end,left-right concepts

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, android-view, android-api-levels

I am little confused regarding usage of below attributes.

```
> android:layout_marginRight and   android:layout_marginEnd
> android:layout_marginLeft and android:layout_marginStart
> android:layout_toLeftOf and android:layout_toStartOf
> android:layout_toRightOf and android:layout_toEndOf
> android:layout_gravity="right|end"
> android:layout_gravity="left|start"
```

Below are the some of facts which i have mentioned.Please correct me if i am wrong.

- To support both Ltr and Rtl layouts  and to support versions prior to api level 17
  is it advisable to put the above attributes always in pairs..
- The "start" and "end" concepts were added in API Level 17 and will
  take precedence for Ltr device with api level>=17  and "right" and "left"
  concepts will take precedence for Ltr device with api level<17
- If our app minskdversion is >=17 then we can ignore "right" and
  "left" attributes and use "start" and "end" attributes only
- The "start" and "end" concepts will take precedence in all Rtl
  devices

Also I would like to know if there is any adverse effect in terms of performance/optimization if i add above attributes in pairs like-

```
 <TextView
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_gravity="right|end"
     android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/dp10"
     android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dp10"
     android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dp10"
     android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/dp10"
     android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/bar"
     android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/bar"
     />
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To support RTL in your apps you should:

- If your app API level >=17 you should use “start” and “end” instead of “left” and “right (for example: layout_marginStart)
- If your app API level <17 then you should add “start” and end” in addition to “left” and “right”. In other words - use both layout_marginRight and layout_marginEnd
  In other words any of your view should look like this:
  android:id="@+id/textView"

  ```
  android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
      android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
      android:text="@string/text_Field"
      android:textSize="24sp"
      android:textStyle="bold"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView" />
  ```

  Note: android:layout_marginStart="16dp"

[Source](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2013/03/native-rtl-support-in-android-42.html)